# Issue with Java StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()

Tags: java, stringescapeutils, apache-commons-lang3

I am trying to escape a string object in my Java application using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4`. I am using **commons-lang3-3.5.jar** library.

Below is the format I am trying to do -

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("user001")
```

When I print in console, the output looks like- `&quot;user001&quot;`

I actually don't want my double quot to be converted into escape characters here. Because, after escaping the string, my program doesn't recognize this as valid string and I am getting malformed JSon. Is there a way to handle this or any better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you escaping HTML if you are using it in JSON? Escaping HTML is for using the string in HTML.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue using the Version 3.5 of the commons-lang3.

Can you share with us more details, please?

Comment: `escapeHTML4` works fine for me and prints no quotes unless the string is `"\"user001\""`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `escapeJava()` instead of `escapeHtml4()`.

> [escapeJava(String input)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String))
>     Escapes the characters in a String using
>   Java String rules.

It won't convert your double quotes to `&quot;` but will simply escape using backslash (which is acceptable in JSON).

---

You can also check

> [escapeJson](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-)
>      *public static final String escapeJson(String input)*
>
> Escapes the characters in a String using Json String rules.
>
> Escapes any values it finds into their Json String form. Deals
>   correctly with quotes and control-chars (tab, backslash, cr, ff, etc.)

Comment: @Raman-Thanks. I want to prevent chances of script injection inside my JSon input. What should I use in this- escapeJava() or escapeJson()?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick they both are almost similar, with the only difference being that in Json, forward-slash (/) is escaped. You can use any of them, however, if you're intending to use it with some JSON parser, then it's better to use `escapeJson()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()`. The problem might be that you are trying to use a plain string, where your code expects JSON.

Comment: Thanks. I want to prevent chances of script injection inside my JSon input. Will the escapeJson() help me?

Comment: Can you share with us more information, please? I am interested in the part that consumes the result of the StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("user001") method.